# How to use a Java method in Scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, scala-java-interop

I have a Java class `package.SStream` where I have implemented the method `getValue()` which returns a `JavaPairDStream<String, Integer>`

I want to use this method in Scala's main method

I've imported the class `package.SStream` in Scala
   and when I try to call the method like this in Scala

```
val x = SStream.getValue()
```

I get this error :

```
[error] value getValue is not a member of object package.SStream
```

Answer (score 1):

That error sounds like your `getValue()` is not a static method.

Is it defined as a static method or an instance method in your `package.SStream` class?